# Excel - how to rank based on number of occurences?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with one column with text strings.

I would like to transfer it to a two column sheet where each line appears once and its count in the 2nd column. Ordered by descending count

For example:
Original:

```
A
B
C
B
A
B
```

Target:

```
B  3
A  2
C  1
```

Please advise. Can it be done without programming?

Comment: Does that mean you want to avoid VBa?

Comment: yes if possible

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the column of source data (i.e. `A, B, C, B, A, B` as in your example)
2. Paste it into a new sheet in the first column
3. Select the new column you've pasted and go to Data > Remove Duplicates. You should now end up with just `A, B, C` etc
4. In the second column, use a `COUNTIF` formula: `=COUNTIF(Sheet1 Range, Sheet2 Cell)`

This will give you a count of the number of instances of each piece of data in the original set. Sort by the second column.

Answer (score 0):

This is not totally automated, but a simple way is to use [COUNTIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
=COUNTIF(Range, Criteria)
```

So, in a new column (I chose F as per screen below), manually type A - D (or what ever your range is) and beside it (column G), use the formula above

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6, F1) // use absolute references
```

Then, drag the formula down!

[image]

After this, you can then use Excel to do any filtering/sorting

Comment: would it not be appropriate to use $A$1:$A$6 instead of A1:A6 ?

Comment: @Prasanna, yes, you're probably right, feel free to edit (Excel isn't my strength but OP didn't want VBa)

Comment: Is it possible to chat with you? I'm trying to learn VBA - i want to know from where to start - quick chat if you can!

Comment: I do not know how to setup chat.... I tried something. Please follow the link http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16371/set-ups

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  No formulas or VBA coding is required. A Query can start from a Table of Excel data - it will automatically adjust as new rows are added or rows are deleted.

The first step in the Query would be a Group By Column A, calculating a Count.  Second step is a Sort on the Count. Done.